# Min & Max of subset of map

Tags: java, performance, optimization

I need to find the minimum and maximum values as I iterate through the map element by element as shown ("index" is the position of the key Array of the map):

```
/**even: lowest, odd: highest*/
private Double[] getLowestAndHighestValues(final int index, final int timeRange, ConcurrentSkipListMap<String, Double> ... maps){

    if(maps != null && maps.length > 0){
        ArrayList<Object[]> keyArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < maps.length; i++){
            try{
                ConcurrentSkipListMap<String, Double> map = maps[i];
                keyArrayList.add(map.keySet().toArray());
            }
            catch(Exception e){

            }
        }

        Double[] values = new Double[maps.length * 2];
        for(int i = index - timeRange; i < index; i++){
            if(i >= 0){
                for(int x = 0; x < maps.length; x++){
                    try{
                        if(x >= 0){
                            ConcurrentSkipListMap<String, Double> map = maps[x];
                            if(map != null){

                                final Object[] keyArray = keyArrayList.get(x);
                                final String key = (String) keyArray[i];
                                Double value = map.get(key);
                                if(value != null && !Double.isNaN(value)){
                                    if(values[x * 2] == null){
                                        values[x * 2] = value;
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        if(values[x * 2] > value){
                                            values[x * 2] = value;
                                        }
                                    }

                                    if(values[(x * 2) + 1] == null){
                                        values[(x * 2) + 1] = value;
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        if(values[(x * 2) + 1] < value){
                                            values[(x * 2) + 1] = value;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch(Exception e){}
                }
            }
        }
        return values;
    }
    return null;
}
```

The crappy code shown above takes an awfully long time and is a real bottleneck, especially when I have to get the min and max of the subset of the map every time the index increments. Does anyone know how I can achieve the same thing (get the highest and lowest values of a subset of every map) faster?

Thanks.

Comment: My eyes are bleeding. Maybe you should rethink your logic to use a second structure to hold min/max everytime you mutate the map.

Comment: The min and max what? The min and max values (doubles)?

Comment: Please clearly state the requirements given your signature. Do you need to return the min & max values of each `Map` for the values whose index are in position `index - timeRange` to `index`? Since this type of Map has its keys sorted in natural order, does `index` as an `int` really apply? Do you indent natural order position or insert order position? Generally using index values in Maps is an anti-pattern.

Comment: I am trying to get the min and max values of the subset of an Array of maps. The map is not changed, but the method is called repeatedly whenever the position of the map element pointer "index" is pointing to increases. Also, I believe that I have included the code, which should tell you what I am trying to do exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, start with a simpler alg.

- For each map

1 Get the array of values

2 Copy the sub-array to a new array from index (index-time, index) using Arrays

3 Sort the sub-array using Arrays

4 Get first and last value

Comment: Sorting is needlessly inefficient here, computing min and max directly is easy.